# Photos not being added to Photostream when added to folder on disk

Tags: icloud, windows

Before I updated to the latest version of iCloud panel on my PC, I could add photos to the location on disk where my icloud stream was saved to and those photos were synced to the stream on any connected devices.

This doesn't seem to happen anymore, I can only add photos therough the control panel.

Is there a way to simply add files to the folder on disk and have them sync, or is there an api for the cloudpanel?